# discord python deleting bot messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord

So i'm just getting into python and Discord and i want to know if it is possible to delete only the messages from the bot. I already have a script that has an error, 'list' object has no attribute 'channel'

```
if message.content.startswith('!clearbeta'):
    list = ['!8ball', '!uptime', '!meme', '!animated meme', '!weeb', '!cute af', '!coin', '!fun', '!reaction']
    await client.delete_message(list)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Cleared messages")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you [read the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_message), I suppose.

`client.delete_message` needs a `Message` object, not a list of strings. Similarly, `client.delete_messages` needs a list of `Message` objects.

You could instead use something like [`client.purge_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from) with a `check` predicate to test if the message content matches something in your list. However, the endpoint for purging has a limit of <= 2 weeks (ie, you can't delete messages older than this).

Comment: thank you very much! i was just blind and didn't see it, although i read through the documentation.